# Unable to publish subfolder under ".well-known" folder from GitHub Page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, lets-encrypt, acme

Tried to set up a GitHub page with a custom domain to fulfill the acme-challenge from cert generation ( Let's Encrypt ).

I managed to publish the `.well-known` folder by adding a `_config.yml` file with `include: [".well-known"]` content.

However, it does not work with the subdirectory of `.well-known/acme-challenge` and have no luck with these configurations `include: [".well-known/acme-challenge", ".well-known", ".well-known/acme-challenge/index.html"]`

The testing commands:

- `curl -v http://exptests.com/.well-known/index.html` << works
- `curl -v http://exptests.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html` << does not work

My repo: https://github.com/blackjackyau/acme/tree/main/docs

Comment: Try dropping an empty `.nojekyll` file into the `docs` directory so you don't have to fight with what Jekyll, the built-in static site generator, takes into account or ignores.

Comment: @BenjaminW. just applied the changes, does not look working so far

Comment: The file is still there, created a pull request to remove it :) Merge and try again.

Comment: @Christian the comment was to introduce a `.nojekyll` file and do I did ( `.nojekyll` file is not there in the first place )

Comment: Do you refer to these challenges: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/ ?

Comment: yes that's the intention of the repo, but the question is mainly on the github page behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried 3 of the approaches separately

- include in _config.yaml
- permalink ([commit](https://github.com/blackjackyau/acme/commit/b71789b09378b5897c9f592dfb23fe2abba5e578))
- `.nojekyll` and `.nojekyll` + include

and all of them are showing the same symptoms that only the acme-challenge URL `.well-known/acme-challenge/xx` is not working ( subdirectory will work if it is not acme-challenge ).

I will conclude that the GitHub page has reserved or prevented the `acme-challenge` path/directory from overwriting. Interesting enough, this was perviously working as mentioned from the [blog](https://adangel.org/2021/09/16/code-signing-lets-encrypt-github-pages/) last year

**Update:**

Github page uses `Lets Encrpyt` to manage SSL for custom domain [(doc)](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https) and this explains why the acme-challenge path is reserved from overwriting